# IA-32 assembly: Effect of 8 bit operations on 32 bit registers

Tags: assembly, x86

During a course in computer science one gave me a binary file and the task to find out what it does, using the technique of reverse engineering (i.e. disassemble the file and analyze it).
I stumbled upon one line of IA-32 instruction:

```
add    %esi,%ecx
```

I learned that commands with suffix `l` operate on 32 bit registers, those with suffix `w` operate on 16 bit registers and I think (but don't know), that operators without suffix operate on 8 bit registers. *Edit: See Ross Ridge's comment which falsifies my assumption.*

So my questions are:

1. Is my assumption above correct?
2. If so, what is the effect (in contrast to `addl`) of the instruction above – and what effects have other operations like `sub`, `mov` and so on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the suffix is ignored/not important if proper register names are given. So the instruction above is a 32 Bit instruction because esi and ecx are 32 Bit registers.

Comment: In the same file there are also occurrences of `addl`. What reasons are there for a compiler to generate sometimes `add` and sometimes `addl` instructions?

Comment: The compiler does not generate different instructions. It is just a matter of the diassembler how it names the instructions. But e.g. in case of `addl $1,(%eax)` the `l` is needed so one knows that a 32 bit value is written

Comment: @user3389669  Note that the absence of a suffix means that the  assembler infers the width of the operation from the operands. The suffix `b` is used when an 8-bit operation needs to be made explicit.

Comment: @FPK Yeah this makes sense - clearly if you say `%eax` versus `%rax` or `%ax` it would be able to tell the difference. Cool, learned something today.

Comment: @user3389669 `addl` is used to disambiguate the cases where arguments size isn't clear. An argument such as `%eax` is 32 bits, and not ambiguous (likewise, `%ax` is 16 bits, and `%al` is 8 bits). A memory reference such as `3(%esi)` is ambiguous because it doesn't indicate the size of the data being referenced. The only way for the assembler to know what size of datum you want to operate on in that case is either in the instruction mnemonic (`addl`, for example, to indicate a 32 bit value), or via a modifier on the argument, such as `dword ptr`, or via the other operand being unambigous.

Comment: A suffix is never *ignored*.  If present, it has to match the registers.  It can be *implied* by the registers if not present.  `addb %esi,%ecx` wouldn't assemble because of the operand-size mismatch, same as `add %al, %ecx` (8 vs. 32-bit register).